# MySQL Select only 1 record on a join including no matches

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that shows a list of users and their last login date. It works "if" they have login history but it doesn't include them if they have no login history. How can I get all the users to show even if they do not have a login history?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS growers.*,ld2.ip,ld2.login_date as last_login 
FROM growers 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM log_logins 
    WHERE user_type = "grower" 
    ORDER BY login_date DESC 
    ) 
as ld2 ON (ld2.user_id = growers.id)
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY growers.id DESC
```

I though the "left" join would include them even if the join did not match anything but it doesn't. The other thing I do not understand is when I delete all log records this query always returns 1 user?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need a left `OUTER` join.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a LEFT JOIN by itself...  Are you returning a single NULL record?  Try returning growers.id instead of ld2.id.

Comment: @BobFincheimer LEFT OUTER join did not change the results of the query.

Comment: @Danny -- nor should it -- they're the same.  Try grouping by growers.id instead of user_id...

Comment: @sgeddes That worked. Thanks! I will accept the answer once it lets me still has a waiting period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `GROUP BY` -- you want to be grouping by `growers.id` not `ld2.user_id` since ld2.user_id could be `NULL`.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS growers.*,ld2.ip,ld2.login_date as last_login 
FROM growers 
   LEFT JOIN ( 
       SELECT * 
       FROM log_logins 
       WHERE user_type = "grower" 
       ORDER BY login_date DESC 
    ) 
   as ld2 ON (ld2.user_id = growers.id)
GROUP BY growers.id 
ORDER BY growers.id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You've the right idea using LEFT JOIN, but I think you can simplify the subquery a little.

Untested, but try this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS growers.*,ld2.ip, ld2.login_date as last_login 
FROM growers 
LEFT JOIN log_logins ld2 ON (user_id = growers.id)
WHERE ld2.login_date = ( SELECT MAX(login_date) FROM log_logins WHERE user_id = ld2.user_id)
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY growers.id DESC
```

(If it's immensely slow, indexing log_logins on both login_date and user_id ought to help a great deal with the subquery!)